# To find intervals in which f takes value equal to 1

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ defined by

$$f(x) = \int_{-5}^x \! (t-1)^3 dt$$

Attempt: I put $f(x) =1$ and after solving I got the interval $(-10,10)$. But that's inconsistent with what my book says. Can someone help? Thanks

Comment: What is your closed form expression for $f(x)$?

Comment: @SimonS i just integrated and solved for t .thats all

Comment: Can you elaborate on your objective here? One can write $f(x) = \dfrac14((x-1)^4 - 6^4)$, and setting $f(x) = 1$ yields $x = 1 \pm \sqrt[4]{4 + 6^4} \simeq 7.00462,-5.00462$.

Comment: @BaronVT so my answer is wrong

Comment: @SophieClad I don't know how you got that answer or what you're trying to accomplish, so I can't say if your answer is wrong or right.

Comment: e.g $(-10,10)$ is *an* interval on which $f$ takes the value $1$ (twice), but so is $(-6,13)$ or $(-734,8)$ or any number of other intervals.

Comment: @BaronVT  i have seen this question .there are 4 intervals given and we have to pick correct ones .They are [-6,0]  , [-2,4]  , [2,8]   [6,12]  .so is it 1,2,3 intervals?

Comment: Oh goodness; this would have been useful information to have at the outset (@SophieClad please take note and include all relevant information in future questions). $[-6,0], [2,8]$ and $[6,12]$ do contain one of these points, $[-2,4]$ does not. (and none of them contain both)

Comment: @SophieClad Hello, IIT JAM 2015 question :)

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't expect you to have an interval for an answer. Solving the integral we get $$\begin{align}f(x) = \frac{1}{4}\left[(t-1)^4\right]_{-5}^x  \\ =\frac{1}{4}\left[(x-1)^4-(-6)^4\right] \\ = \frac{1}{4}\left[(x-1)^4-1296\right]  \end{align}$$ Now we proceed as you said, setting $f(x)=1$ to get $$\begin{align} 1 = \frac{1}{4}\left[(x-1)^4-1296\right]  \end{align} \\ \implies 4 =(x-1)^4-1296 \\ \implies 1300 = (x-1)^4 \\ \implies \pm \sqrt[4]{1300}=x-1 \\ \implies x = 1\pm \sqrt[4]{1300} $$ 
So you get two values for $x$, which is not enough to make an interval. But these values satisfy the equation you are after.

Comment: Beat me to the punch ;)